# Test Hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I need help solving the following problem. I exhausted many options however I fell short. Any help is appreciated.

Creative Good, a New York consulting firm, claimed that 35% of shoppers fail in their attempt to purchase merchandise on-line because Web sites are too complex. A random sample of 60 on-line shoppers was selected and 15 reported sufficient frustration with their sites to deter making a purchase.  Do these data provide sufficient evidence that percentage of shoppers fail in their attempt to purchase on-line differs from 35% ?

Mainly need help with the bolded questions!

a. Set up the null and alternate hypothesis

**b. Calculate the test statistic.**

**c. Draw the curve and find the critical value(s).**

[Work done so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHKrE.jpg)

Comment: Too many questions and no effort. What do you expect ?

Comment: There was an effort, help me start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hypotheses and the test statistic, $T=-1.624$, are right. Your t-value is not right. The parameter $n$ at $t_{n-1,\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ and $t_{n-1,1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ is the sample size. Therefore $n-1=59$. Now it depends what significance level you decide to take. Let´s say it is $\alpha=10\%=0.1$. Thus $\frac{\alpha}{2}=0.05$ and $ 1-\frac{\alpha}{2}=1-0.05=0.95$.

$t_{59,0.05}=-1.671$

$t_{59,0.95}=1.671$

Therefore T is inside the 90% interval, because $-1.671<-1.624<1.671$

$H_0$ can not be rejected at the significance level of $10\%$. You have the two critical values. That means that you have two areas (left and right) which represents the lower 5% and the upper 5% of the t-distribution.

**Remark**

Because of the thumb rule $n\cdot p \cdot (1-p)>9$ the t-distribution can be approximated by the normal distribution.

$z_{0.05}=-1.645$ and $z_{0.95}=1.645$. The test statistic is inside the confidence interval again.

Comment: This makes much more sense. I kept getting confused with my t-value. I was also using n to be 15 instead of using the sample size. Thank you callculus. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @BhavikP. You are welcome. I´m sure that you will manage to draw the graph with the two tails.

Comment: yes, I think I got that part under control

Answer (score -2):

its a p test from what I understood so test statistic is from $z=(p'-p)/((pq/n)^{.5})$

Comment: Please look at the edit of the work I have done. Does it look accurate?